# this.proxy.on method not receiving any response

Tags: jquery, angularjs, signalr

i have been using this for two days today suddenly stop working any clue?

hub

```
public class MyHub1 : Hub
{
    private CompanyConnectionSessionMapBLL _namesAdapter = null;
    protected CompanyConnectionSessionMapBLL Adapter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_namesAdapter == null)
                _namesAdapter = new CompanyConnectionSessionMapBLL();

            return _namesAdapter;
        }
    }
public void sendPauseSignalToThePaitentViewScreen(string signal, string companyID, string sessionID)
    {
        List<CompanyConnectionSessionMap> listOfConnections = Adapter.GetConnectionsByCompanyAndStatus(Convert.ToInt32(companyID), 1);
        foreach (CompanyConnectionSessionMap connection in listOfConnections)
        {
            //Clients.Client(connection.ConnectionID).sendPauseSignal(signal);
            Clients.All.sendPauseSignal(signal);
        }
    }
}
```

Angular Controller

```
.controller('SessionController', ['$scope', 'DoctorSessionService', '$stateParams', function ($scope, DoctorSessionService, $stateParams) {

$scope.init = function () {
    //to load signalr
    DoctorSessionService.initialize($stateParams.docId);
}
$scope.init();

$scope.$on('eventPause', function (event, data) {
    if (data.data == "Pause") {
        $("#dvPause").show();
    } else if (data.data == "Resume") {
        $("#dvPause").hide();
    }
})
}])
```

Angular Service

```
 .value('$', $)
.factory('DoctorSessionService', ['$q', '$timeout', 'AjaxCallerFactory', '$', '$rootScope', function ($q, $timeout, AjaxCallerFactory, $, $rootScope) {
    return {
        proxy: null,
        test: [],
        test1: [],
    initialize: function (docId) {
        //Getting the connection object
        connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:60255');

        //Creating proxy
        this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('MyHub1');

        //Starting connection
        connection.start({ jsonp: true })

        .done(function () {
            console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
            var params = {
                companyConnectionSessionMap: {
                    CompanyID: docId,
                    ConnectionID: connection.id,
                    SessionID: 0
                }
            };

            AjaxCallerFactory.ajaxPost("http://localhost:60255/CompanyConnectionSessionMap/SaveCompanyConnectionSessionMap", params);

        })
        .fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect!'); });


        this.proxy.on('sendPauseSignal', function (message) {
            alert(message)
            $rootScope.$broadcast('eventPause', {
                data: message
            });
        });


    }
}
}])
```

There is no console errors and connection is connecting properly. i'm using jquery.signalr-2.2.0.js

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue proxy.on method should come before starting the connection

```
.value('$', $)
.factory('DoctorSessionService', ['$q', '$timeout', 'AjaxCallerFactory', '$', '$rootScope', function ($q, $timeout, AjaxCallerFactory, $, $rootScope) {
    return {
        proxy: null,
        test: [],
        test1: [],
    initialize: function (docId) {
        //Getting the connection object
        connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:60255');

    //Creating proxy
    this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('MyHub1');



    this.proxy.on('sendPauseSignal', function (message) {
        alert(message)
        $rootScope.$broadcast('eventPause', {
            data: message
        });
    });

    //Starting connection
    connection.start({ jsonp: true })

    .done(function () {
        console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);
        var params = {
            companyConnectionSessionMap: {
                CompanyID: docId,
                ConnectionID: connection.id,
                SessionID: 0
            }
        };

        AjaxCallerFactory.ajaxPost("http://localhost:60255/CompanyConnectionSessionMap/SaveCompanyConnectionSessionMap", params);

    })
    .fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect!'); });


}
```

}
}])